# How do you solve an equation when you have both y and ln(y)?

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

I'm trying to solve the equation $x = 8 + y + \ln (y-3)$ for $y$, but am having trouble isolating $y$. How can I get the $y$ out of the ln function without making the other $y$ the exponent of $e$?

Comment: This most likely can't by solved by hand in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @ZacharySelk This function is the inverse of f, but the question asks for f^-1(f(17)). Is there a way to find that value without finding the inverse?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . What is your precise problem?

Comment: I guess that's 17. If the function f is one-to-one and thus $f^{-1}$ is defined everywhere, then $f^{-1}f(17)=17.$

Comment: @QingZhang Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Lambert function W:

$x-11=y-3 + \ln(y-3)$

$e^{x-11}=(y-3)e^{y-3}$

$y-3=W(e^{x-11})$